# Define default selection if no data in db - Symfony EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

This is code I use to show filed in page.

I need some way to predefine default selected if there is no data.
Any suggestion?

```
->add('period', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'empty_value' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'class' => 'MainBundle\Entity\NotificationsPeriod',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
                $qb->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
                $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->notIn('u.id', 1));
                return $qb;
            },
            'empty_data' => 2,
        ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there!

You need to set your `empty_data` parameter as you have to match a value in your HTML.

For example:

```
//formClass.php
'empty_data' => 2,
```

Then ..

```
//template.twig
<select name="whatever">
  <option value="2">Something</option>
  {# build your options from data.. #}
</select>
```

The official docs are here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data